# SimpleForm validation and Angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

We use simple form in our project and now I just created a form which is loaded as an angular template. I would also like to handle validation using angular, but take errors from a response. Do you know any ready to go angular directives for handling validation errors of simple form?

Comment: validation is built into angular forms, unless you need something specific that it doesn't handle. It's kind of hard to tell because what you are asking here is a bit broad  - but you can check out the built in validation here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the form validation strategy for angularjs forms:

1. ng-minlength : specify the minimum length of the input text you want
2. ng-maxlength : specify the maximum length of the input text you want
3. ng-pattern   : specify a js regular expression to be checked for validating input text
4. if you have an api and want to get a unique value in a field than tune in this code snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('validationExample', []);

app.directive('ensureUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/check/' + attrs.ensureUnique,
          data: {'field': attrs.ensureUnique}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
          c.$setValidity('unique', data.isUnique);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
          c.$setValidity('unique', false);
        });
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

```
var app = angular.module('validationExample', []);

app.directive('ensureUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/check/' + attrs.ensureUnique,
          data: {'field': attrs.ensureUnique}
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
          c.$setValidity('unique', data.isUnique);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
          c.$setValidity('unique', false);
        });
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

You can access your form fields in this way

```
formName.inputFieldName.property
```

You can check whether form is touched by the user or not

```
formName.inputFieldName.$pristine;
```

You can check whether form is touched by the user or not opposite of $pristine

```
formName.inputFieldName.$dirty
```

You can check whether form is valid or not

```
formName.inputFieldName.$valid
```

Its opposite of $valid

```
formName.inputFieldName.$invalid
```

you can also format your form using these class names

```
.ng-pristine {}
.ng-dirty {}
.ng-valid {}
.ng-invalid {}
```